# global vs local .gitignore conflict

Tags: git, gitignore

I've set a global .gitignore like this

```
# global .gitconfig
[core]
  quotepath = false
  excludesfile = ~/.gitignore_global
```

Where `~/.gitignore_global` is something like this:

```
# https://www.gitignore.io/api/pycharm

# User-specific stuff:
.idea/**/workspace.xml
.idea/**/tasks.xml
.idea/**/vcs.xml
.idea/**/jsLibraryMappings.xml
# .idea/**/dictionaries

# Sensitive or high-churn files:
.idea/**/dataSources/
.idea/**/dataSources.ids
.idea/**/dataSources.xml
.idea/**/dataSources.local.xml
.idea/**/sqlDataSources.xml
.idea/**/dynamic.xml
.idea/**/uiDesigner.xml

# Gradle:
.idea/**/gradle.xml
.idea/**/libraries

# Mongo Explorer plugin:
.idea/**/mongoSettings.xml

## File-based project format:
*.iws

## Plugin-specific files:
# IntelliJ
/out/

# mpeltonen/sbt-idea plugin
.idea_modules/

# JIRA plugin
atlassian-ide-plugin.xml

# Crashlytics plugin (for Android Studio and IntelliJ)
com_crashlytics_export_strings.xml
crashlytics.properties
crashlytics-build.properties
fabric.properties
```

So now whenever I start a new project with any intellij IDE only some files inside the `.idea`folder will be tracked and others won't. So fa so good.

The problem comes from a project I had started before setting up the .gitignore_global. In fact within this project I had setup a local .gitignore to ignore the `.idea/` folder altogether.

```
# local .gitignore created before the global one
*.idea/
```

Now, for that old project I want to start to track the relevant files within the `.idea` folder, so I've commented the line `# *.idea/`.

And here starts the problem.

Instead of just tracking the relevant files as stated in `.gitignore_global` it mark as new file (unstaged) ALL the files within the .idea folder, **ignoring** the `.gitignore_global` (sorry for the redundancy).

I suspect (not sure) that back then, years ago I had accidentally added the `.idea` folder to the repo, then removed, then ignored.

How can I fix this? I want to track only the relevant files in .idea not marked as ignored by following the instruction from `.gitignore_global`.

**EDIT**: the important part is that git let me add all the new files to the staging area even the ones t not supposed to.

Comment: Having had the files under previous commits shouldn't matter. (If it did matter, you'd have had problems even when locally .gitignore-ing the entire directory.)  More likely the config for that repo is somehow not set up correctly to use the global ignore file.

Comment: I've opened the .git/config file of the repo and it doesn't seem to have anything abnormal. It's similar to other config from other projects that are actually working as excpected

Comment: Hmm... well, I did a quick test - including adding 3 files in a directory, committing; removing the files from the index, ignoring the directory, committing; adding a global ignore for one of the files, commenting out the local ignore for the directory.  `git status` then reported `foo/` as untracked, but when I `add`ed it, it only staged the two files as expected...  So something else is wrong.

Comment: Your local `.gitignore` does not have the same rules as you global `.gitignore_global`. Are you positive that, among, the files listed as "untracked", some match one of the global ignore rules ?

Comment: Yes, as example I can stage `.idea/workspace.xml` where the global ignore explicitly denies it with `.idea/**/workspace.xml`

Comment: Note that `a/b/c.txt` matches `a/**/*.txt`, but `a/c.txt` does not!  The `**` expansion here must be non-empty. To keep Git from adding files like `.idea/workspace.xml`, you can include `.idea/*.xml` as well as `.idea/**/*.xml`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that I had 2 `.idea/` directories.

One was create by pycharm at the first level, where also the `.git` dir lives and the other one buried down several levels targeting my webapp created by webstorm.

The one at the first level was correctly adding/ignoring files, the one deep down wasn't.

The trivial reason was that regexs like this `.idea/**/workspace.xml` on my global gitignore were only targeting first level dir.

To make this work wherever the .idea dir would live inside my repo I had to change those regexs to the form `**/.idea/**/workspace.xml`.